# Handle new dynamic table creation in a div in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am currently doing web UI automation using Robot Framework. For my current task I have a div tag which shows a table inside. The table only shows 25 elements at load time. See image of elements for reference.
[image: Initial Structure On Load]

After scrolling the top div tag slowly, it creates new set of tables. See below image:
[image: After scrolling]

The point is it doesn't show all tables at one go. Also it keeps on adding tables with _startrow attribute to a random value. It also deletes tables from earlier rows on scrolling.

I am not sure how to deal with such dynamic content. Using `Execute Javascript` keyword has not helped as well.

Any new help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is a bit specific (on the js framework, and the html it produces), but I'll take a stab of providing a bit generic answer - with pseudo code you'll need to adapt.

What does a user do to make sure the new data is loaded? They see an entry, scroll a bit, wait for that entry to disappear, and for a new one to be visualized. So let's try to simulate it; "see" the current entry:

```
${old table}=    Get Webelement    ${locator for a generic table in the div}   # something like //div/table[@summary=“Task Types“]
```

Now the value of that variable is going to be a specific webelement - an actual object in the DOM, not the "current `<table>` tag in the html, in any given moment".

Then, you do the operation that will make the system reload the tables - and wait for the one that was present to disappear:

```
Operation So Data Is Changed
Wait Until Element Is Not Visible    ${old table}
```

Once the "Wait For" returns execution/completes, you are sure the old table is no longer visible. And then - you need to wait for the new one to appear:

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${locator for a generic table in the div}   # something like //div/table[@summary=“Task Types“]
```

This approach is based off the SeleniumLibrary, and YMMV on the exact operations and locators, but that's the general idea.